# `fullVisitorId` => clientId, one-to-many mapping?

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I'm under the impression `fullVisitorId` being just a hash of clientId, there should be one-to-one mapping between the two. But here, I've a situation where few of the `fullVisitorId` are mapped to two different `client Id` (we're collecting GA Client ID into User scoped custom dimensions)

Is that possible ? under what circumstances?

Thanks for any clarification on this

Cheers!

[edit: ] attaching screenshot[image]

Comment: sorry, just to add some context, this is re: Google Analytics export to BigQuery

Comment: As far as I know there's no circumstance where a fullvisitorid gets associated to different ga client ids. I just checked in our BigQuery and for the last month we had 0 ocurrences for that. Maybe could it be that some bug is going on when you are saving the ga client id?

Comment: Thanks Will for confirming, Thats our understanding as well! How come hashed fullVisitorId be traced to multiple clientIDs It's gotta be 1:1 mapping between the two..

Comment: I recommend you to check how the ga client id is being generated and saved to ga. Maybe something went wrong there (either a javascript code or something)

Answer (score 2):

You may be interested in reading about the [Google Analytics schema for BigQuery](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437719?hl=en). Some of the relevant parts are:

- `fullVisitorId`: The unique visitor ID (also known as client ID).
- `visitId`: An identifier for this session. This is part of the value usually stored as the _utmb cookie. This is only unique to the user. For a completely unique ID, you should use a combination of fullVisitorId and visitId.

So client ID and full visitor ID are synonymous, and if you want a unique ID for a particular visit, you should use a combination of `fullVisitorId` and `visitId`.

Comment: If I switch devices, will the fullvisitorID change?