# Why there are multiple client Ids associated with same fullVisitorId in BigQuery, I'm collecting client as an custom dimension

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

Why there are multiple client Ids associated with same fullVisitorId in Bigquery? I'm collecting client as an custom dimension.

Comment: go through : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: some important information for you to add in your question: how are you retrieving fullvisitorids and clientids? How are you saving the client id? is it happening to all visitors?

Comment: This looks like the same question as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44516452/fullvisitorid-clientid-one-to-many-mapping.